# Calculate marginal tax rates using R

Tags: r

I'm writing a function to calculate tax owed given a level of income according to [Australia's marginal tax rates](https://www.ato.gov.au/rates/individual-income-tax-rates/).

I've written a simple version of the function that results in the correct amount of tax owed using the following:

```
income_tax <- function(income) {
# Calculate income tax liability based on income
#
# Returns the amount of income tax owed

    if (income > 0 & income <= 18200) {
        tax <- 0
        } else if (income > 18200 & income <= 37000) {
        tax <- (income - 18200) * .19
        } else if (income > 37000 & income <= 80000) {
        tax <- 3572 + (income - 37000) * .325
        } else if (income > 80000 & income <= 180000) {
        tax <- 17547 + (income - 80000) * .37
        } else if (income > 180000) {
        tax <- 54547 + (income - 180000) * .45
        }
    return(tax)
}
```

The problem with this approach is that I've hard-coded the rates and the amount paid in each bracket into the logic. This makes the function fragile, and means I can't test out different rates or brackets (which is my ultimate aim).

What I'd like to do is have the logic generated from a tax rates table.

Here's a version of what I'd like to do with the alorithm written in pseudo code as a comment.

```
income_tax <- function(income) {
# Calculate income tax liability based on income
#
# Returns the amount of income tax owed
brackets <- c(18200,37001,80000,180000,180000)
rates <- c(0,.19,.325,.37,.45)
tax_rates <- data.frame(brackets, rates)

for (i in 1:nrow(tax_rates)) {
    # if income is in bracket_X then:
    # tax <- (income - bracket_X[i-1]) * rate_X + minimum_tax_from_bracket_X[-1]
    }

return(tax)
}
```

My problem is that I can't conceptualise or code how to generate the amount of tax owed and the marginal rates while the data is encoded like this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's a one-liner that does the trick:

```
income_tax <- 
function(income,
         brackets = c(18200, 37000, 80000, 180000, Inf),
         rates = c(0, .19, .325, .37, .45)) {        
    sum(diff(c(0, pmin(income, brackets))) * rates)
}
```

Perhaps the easiest way to see how/why it works is to play around with the core bit of logic with some simpler parameters, like this:

```
brackets <- c(1:5, Inf)

diff(c(0, pmin(.35, brackets)))
## [1] 0.35 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
diff(c(0, pmin(3.9, brackets)))
## [1] 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.9 0.0 0.0
diff(c(0, pmin(99, brackets)))
## [1]  1  1  1  1  1 94
```

Comment: I'm giving it to this one as it's the simplest and it's also taught me about two functions pmin and diff. The other answers also work, but this is the most elegant.

Comment: This is beautiful.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for `findInterval`:

```
income_tax <- function(income, 
                       brackets = c(0, 18200, 37000, 80000, 180000, 180000),
                       rates = c(0, .19, .325, .37, .45)) {
  bracketInd <- findInterval(income, brackets, all.inside = TRUE)
  plus <- if (bracketInd <= 2) 0 else 
    sum(sapply(bracketInd:3, function(ind) {
      (brackets[ind] - brackets[ind - 1]) * rates[ind - 1] 
    }))
  if (length(plus) == 0) plus <- 0
  tax <- plus + (income - brackets[bracketInd]) * rates[bracketInd]
  return(tax)
}
```

You just find between each elements your `income` is, and use that as an index for `brackets` and the `rates`. I also added the values as parameters with default values.

Comment: you haven't provided a way to calculate the ``plus`` parameter when the ``brackets`` parameter changes, which in my opinion is an important aspect of the question.

Comment: also the function incorrectly returns ``NA`` when ``income`` exceeds ``tail(brackets,1)``.

Comment: @nathanesau 1. That's a fixed value that makes the scale continuous. It only changes every year and he didn't ask to calculate that on the fly, though it indeed depends on the other variables. 2. That's fixed.

Comment: Though it might not be his final goal, it solves the problem of using different brackets and rates.

Comment: Yes I need to dynamically calculate the `plus` or `cumtax` variable so that I can change the rates and have the output be correct.

Comment: my solution already accounts for this, so should suit your needs. however, I do think that using the ``findInterval()`` function as ``Molx`` did is a good way to go.

Comment: @TomMcMahon There you go. Removed it as argument and now calculates based on both rates and brackets.

Comment: still doesn't give the right output since ``plus`` is wrong. for instance, tax for ``income = 100000`` should be 24947

Comment: @nathanesau Yep, I forgot to make it cumulative, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

I slightly changed your `brackets` and `rates` parameters. You can solve this problem using a `while` loop.

```
income_tax <- function(income,
    brackets = c(18200,37001,80000,180000),
    rates = c(.19,.325,.37,.45))
{
  nbrackets <- length(brackets)  
  if(income<=brackets[1]) 
    return(0)

  i <- 2
  cumtax <- 0
  while(i <= nbrackets) {
    if(income > brackets[i-1] && income < brackets[i]) 
      return(cumtax + rates[i-1]*(income-brackets[i-1]))
    else 
      cumtax <- cumtax + rates[i-1]*(brackets[i]-brackets[i-1])
      i <- i + 1
  }
  # income > brackets[nbrackets]
  cumtax + rates[nbrackets] * (income - brackets[nbrackets]) 
}

incomes <- seq(0,200000,25000)
round(sapply(incomes,income_tax),0)
# [1]     0  1292  7797 15922 24947 34197 43447 52697 63547
```

Comment: This works, but the findInterval answer seems to get at the problem more elegantly.