# Calculate marginal tax rates using R, applied to a list

Tags: r

I am using O'Brien's approach to solve this problem:

[Calculate marginal tax rates using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33770639/calculate-marginal-tax-rates-using-r)

I am trying to apply the basic formula

```
> sum(diff(c(0, pmin(income, brackets))) * rates)
```

from O'Brien's function:

```
income_tax <- 
function(income,
         brackets = c(18200, 37000, 80000, 180000, Inf),
         rates = c(0, .19, .325, .37, .45)) {        
    sum(diff(c(0, pmin(income, brackets))) * rates)
}
```

to a list:

```
income <- c(16000, 45000, 200000, 150000)
```

I get the following warnings:

> Warning messages: 1: In pmin():   an
>   argument will be fractionally recycled 2: In diff() :   longer
>   object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Along with output from the last element in the income list

Expected output is also a list of tax amounts calculated by the basic formula

Could someone point me in the right direction?  Or is there a more elegant way of going about this?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: It's not an error. In R warnings are different than errors. If you want tested code you should provide everything needed to make your code run. In this case that means at the very least `rates` and `brackets`.

Comment: It looks like the `income_tax` function was mean to be used with a single (scalar) value for "income". I'm guessing that you are sending it a vector of incomes instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I also encountered this issue and I would like to share my solution in case any one in the future needs it.

The original function applies to a scalar rather than a vector. This is because the `pmin` function treats the `income` input as a vector with the same length as the `bracket` vector, and returns the parallel minima.

One way to apply a function to a vector of income is to use `sapply`:

```
income <- c(16000, 45000, 200000, 150000)

sapply(income, income_tax)

# [1] 0  6172 63547 43447
```

If applying the function in a dataframe using `dplyr`, you can use `rowwise()`:

```
y <- data.frame(income = c(16000, 45000, 200000, 150000))
y %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(tax = income_tax(income))

# income   tax
# <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  16000     0
# 2  45000  6172
# 3 200000 63547
# 4 150000 43447
```